# Redirect to outside server

Tags: redirects

I am trying to redirect a template to an outside website in EE2, I have tried this:

```
    {redirect='http://other_website.com/whatever/12/'}
```

It puts the url of the host before the url I put there because it's expecting a template.

```
    http://myhost.com/http://other_website.com/whatever/12/
```

Is there any way to redirect it properly?

Thanks!

PS: In EE1, I have used:

```
    {exp:redirect_to location="http://www.yahoo.com"}
```

but it's not working now.

Answer (score 1):

You might use [RedirectURL EE2 Plugin](https://github.com/webrgp/RedirectURL-EE2-Plugin) for redirection in EE2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/redirectee This plugin will use the `header()` function from PHP